# Downloading a file from a Subscription website ( PHP pages ) using C#

Tags: c#, php, forms, download, submit

I'm a Asp.Net C# developer and I want to download a CSV file from a PHP Site.
Apologize if this has already been covered, but in this case, the Link is showing javascript form submit.

Right now we login on the  login page
and then enter a date on the search page.
The results page shows the results in Html and also has a "download" link which when clicked will server  a CSV file.

We would like to "pull" the CSV file periodically via some Screen Scraping / download of the file.

The "download" link  shows the following javascript to submit a form back to the server to download the CSV file:

```
javascript:document.aForm.action='download.php'; setTarget();document.aForm.submit();
```

I want to setup a C# console application to run periodically to:
Login, and download the CSV file.

1. Can I use the  webclient  downloaddata method to access this CSV file ?
   A code sample please.
2. Can I do some programmatic scraping to login and fill in some search criteria 
   and get to the results page to download the csv ?

What is recommended to this ? html agility pack ?
any links or code snippets is greatly appreciated.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: You need to replicate the functionality of the setTarget() javascript in your console client - that is, you need to fill in whatever form field changes or (I suspect) URL query string manipulations are being done there. Everything else is just simple authenticated request land - the part that is non-obvious from your question is what setTarget() is actually doing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class and for downloading a file you can use [`WebClient.DownloadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx) method

OR

You can you `Curl` [`libcurl .net`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html)  for reference you can follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686598/downloading-image-via-libcurl)

To login to a specific Page you can try this

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
byte[] bret = client.UploadData("http://www.website.com/post.php", "POST",
            System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("field1=value1&amp;field2=value2") );

string sret = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bret);
```

Once you have got success response, you can parse that response string to get that hyperlink, and then use `Webclient.DownloadFile` to download file

```
    try
    {
        client.DownloadFile("http://www.xyz.com/download.php","abc.csv");
        Console.WriteLine("File Saved.");
    }
    catch (WebException we)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(we.Message + "\n" + we.Status.ToString());
    }
    catch (NotSupportedException ne)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ne.Message);
    }
```

And i guess in your case that hyperlink `javascript` is doing a post to `download.php`, so instead of using `webclient.downloadFile` you can simple do a post manually using `webclient`. above i have shown you how to post.

Comment: Thanks for the response, could you give me a code snippet on how to access that download.php page that is triggered by the javascript form submit ( hyperlink  url triggered ).

Comment: The MSDN help shows this but in my case I don't know the filename. There is a hyperlink on the page that has javascript to submit a form back to back download.php on the server which will "serve" the CSV file.

string remoteUri = "http://www.contoso.com/library/homepage/images/";
string fileName = "ms-banner.gif", myStringWebResource = null;
   
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
myStringWebResource = remoteUri + fileName;
myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource,fileName);

Comment: may i know wheather that `download.php` is protected with login ? and do you want to get login from c# console to get the file ??